# How do I delete a Data Extension using the Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest

I can create rows but I cannot delete them. How do I do this using the Rest API?

Comment: Also, how do I delete a row in a data extension.

Comment: Can you please come up in brief about your question? Your question doesn't see what you really want to do and how you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with REST APIs. You would need to use SOAP to perform more tasks on data extensions.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/deleting_a_row_from_a_data_extension_via_the_web_service_api/

`<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <DeleteRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
             <Options></Options>
             <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                 <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                 <CustomerKey>FIRST SEND</CustomerKey>
                <Keys>
                   <Key>
                      <Name>EMAIL</Name>
                      <Value>test@example.com</Value>
                   </Key>
                </Keys>
             </Objects>
          </DeleteRequest>
        </s:Body>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the DML operations you may do so all written in Apex class annotated via `RestResource`. Define some REST methods there like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, ACCEPT etc. and you're good to go.

You may call these methods from outside the Salesforce by first logging in and then calling the methods using `HTTP` helper methods. For other languages like Java or .Net you may go for using `HTTP Client`.

You may consider following for this:

You need to create a web service using the `@RestResource` annotation like the following in Apex class:

```
    @RestResource (urlMapping='/person/v1/*')
    global class ContactService{
        @HttpPost
        global static void deleteMethod(String name){ // let's say you want to delete a contact named Contact123 as: DELETE /person/123
           Contact c= [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE name like: name];
           if(c!=null)
               delete c;
        }

    }
```

I'm considering connected App case here. You need to obtain the `client secret` and `client id` for that. And use those for obtaining refresh token (`Access Token`) and call the method above via `POST` call.

You can't use `@HttpDelete` here if you want to delete any specific record coz Delete and GET calls don't accept parameters.

Comment: This question relates to marketing cloud. Your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, no problems :)